# CSS 500 error cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I'm pretty new to cakephp and php in general.  I've been developing a small web app, mostly front end with cakephp on a WAMP server.  Everything was working fine until I deployed it to a live site.  This isn't the only app on this server, so where my route on my local WAMP is `localhost/home/page` on live it's `domain/newsite/app/home/page`.  On the live site it's giving a 500 error when trying to load in the css files.

What am I missing?  Thanks in advance!

My .htaccess files are as follow.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My css files are loaded in with the following:

```
echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap');
echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap_top_carousel');
echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap_overrides');
echo $this->fetch('css');
```

Comment: Do you have these css files directly in the webroot/css folder?

Comment: @CatalinMunteanu yes, that's exactly where they are.

Answer (score 0):

For many hosting services, your web server is actually being served from a user directory. If you are installing CakePHP into a user directory, or any other URL structure that already utilizes mod_rewrite, you'll need to add RewriteBase statements to the .htaccess files CakePHP uses (/.htaccess, /app/.htaccess, /app/webroot/.htaccess).

This can be added to the same section with the RewriteEngine directive, so for example, your .htaccess files would look like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /path/to/cake/app
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /path/to/cake/app
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /path/to/cake/app
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Of course you need to replace `RewriteBase /path/to/cake/app` with your path to the 
CakePHP installation directory.